# ANTLR - Writing a tree grammar for an AST

Tags: c#, lua, antlr, tree-grammar

I have an AST outputted for some Lua code by my grammar file, which currently does parsing and lexing for me. I want to add a tree grammar to this, but since i'm using C# i'm not sure how to do it. What's the basic process for generating tree grammar code when you already have a parser and lexer written?

UPDATE: I have the following grammar file:

```
tree grammar LuaGrammar;

options {
  backtrack=true;
  language=CSharp2;
  //output=AST;
  tokenVocab=Lua;
  filter=true;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}
@lexer::namespace{/*my namespace*/}
@parser::namespace{/*my namespace*/}

dummyRule
    :   ^('=' x=. y=.) {};
```

placed in the same directory as my main grammar file, which generates fine. However, when trying to compile this i get the following errors:

```
[02:54:06] error(143): C:\Users\RCIX\Desktop\AguaLua\Project\trunk\AguaLua\AguaLua\ANTLR Data\LuaGrammar.g:12:18: unknown or invalid action scope for tree grammar: lexer
[02:54:06] error(143): C:\Users\RCIX\Desktop\AguaLua\Project\trunk\AguaLua\AguaLua\ANTLR Data\LuaGrammar.g:13:19: unknown or invalid action scope for tree grammar: parser
```

Am i on the right track or totally off?

Comment: what version of Antlr are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not encountered this error but there are 2 things I would try.

1) remove the @lexer and @parser namespace lines.

2) If they are necessary then move them until after the Tokens {...} section of your grammar, ie just before the rules.

Comment: Ok, but you can edit in your new information :) I probably need to find the equivalent statement for tree grammar rules...

Comment: 1) fixed it, i'll muddle along from here :)

Answer (score 2):

Well going back to my usual example of a calculator grammar:)

This is how you would declare your Tree Walker class

```
class CalcTreeShaker extends TreeParser;

expr returns [float r]
{
float a,b;
r=0;
}
:   #(PLUS a=expr b=expr)   {r = a+b;}
|   #(STAR a=expr b=expr)   {r = a*b;}
|   i:INT           {r = Convert.ToSingle(i.getText());}
;
```

Here we have a tree rule called `expr`.  Tree walkers are very similar to parser grammars.

The big difference is that while a parser grammar has to match exactly a tree grammar only has to match a portion of the tree.

In the `expr` rule we can see it matches any tree that has the tokens `PLUS` or `STAR` or `INT`.

We can see we are matching trees because we are using Antlr's Tree syntax `#(...)`.

The `PLUS` and `STAR` tree's also match 2 expr rules.  Each expr rule is assigned to a name so we can use it to evaluate the expression.  Similar to parser grammars we can put C# code into blocks defiend by `{...}`.

Also note that in this example we show how to return a value from a TreeWalker rule, we use the syntax `return [...]`.

To call the tree walker you create it and then call it's top level rule.  I"ll copy this from the Antlr example:)

```
// Get the ast from your parser.
CommonAST t = (CommonAST)parser.getAST();

// Create the Tree Shaker
CalcTreeWalker walker = new CalcTreeWalker();
CalcParser.initializeASTFactory(walker.getASTFactory());

// pass the ast to the walker and call the top level rule.
float r = walker.expr(t);
```

Comment: That is very helpful but at this point i'm trying to get a valid file which i can persuade ANTLR to compile into some code, maybe i'm missing something...